# Friendly URL shows a part of it twice after loading the page

Tags: php, .htaccess, friendly-url

I have learnt a bit to use .Htaccess from Stackoverflow to rewrite URLs and successfully could achieve the task. However, I see some abnormal change in the same friendly URL when the page is accessed. Let show you what is happening.

friendly URL is

```
http://localhost/CRDLabsphp/PHP/recursive
```

which goes succeffully to and displays the contents from

```
detailspage.php?category=$1
```

But when you click on the same friendly URL

```
http://localhost/CRDLabsphp/PHP/recursive
```

It goes to

```
http://localhost/CRDLabsphp/PHP/PHP/recursive
```

Hence, object not found page. I don't see where the additional "PHP"(category name) comes from. The code that generates the URL is as follows.

```
elseif(isset($finalarray)) {
    ?>
<h2 class="left"><span class="left_h2"><?php echo $finalcategory; ?></span></h2>
<?php   
 foreach ( $finalarray as $key=>$value ) {
 $new_friendly_url = friendly_seo_string($value['article_title']);         
?>   
<a target="_top" href="<?php echo $finalcategory; ?>/<?php echo $new_friendly_url; ?>"><?php echo $value['article_title']; ?></a>
<?php } } else { ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case you need to add '/' symbol:

```
<a target="_top" href="/<?php echo $finalcategory; ?>/<?php echo $new_friendly_url; ?>"><?php echo $value['article_title']; ?></a>
```

Comment: Hi Dehood, I added '/' but the link goes now to 'http://localhost/PHP/variables' instead of 'http://localhost/CRDLabsphp/PHP/variables' which means the roor folder(CRDLabsphp) is missing from the link. Any idea?

Comment: have you tried to add '/CRDLabsphp' to link? Try this: href="/CRDLabsphp/<?php echo $finalcategory; ?>/<?php echo $new_friendly_url; ?>"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't add '/CRDLabsphp'. All the links now lead to the right page except for my logo link which goes to http://localhost/CRDLabsphp/PHP/CRDLabsphp/index.php instead of http://localhost/CRDLabsphp/index.php. What is this behavior termed as?. Please help me find the solution for this. Thanks again.

Comment: Try same method with url. Could you give me a link you are using for logo?

Comment: I just solved it! Everything is working as expected unless I go through other links on the page. I am grateful for the help and time.

Comment: Please tell me what is this kind of programmatic behaviour?

Comment: @Pramod im glad it helped! You can read more about it: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Although all is working with respect to .Htaccess, I see that CSS is not getting applied to the details page.

Comment: ,Just resolved the issue by placing the /rootfoldername/ before the paths to css/js/images links. I am sure there must be a smarter way than this. Would be glad to know.